# In Plunderer, what does Licht's -999 count mean?

Tags: plunderer

In episode 2 (possibly even 1) of *Plunderer*, Nana refers to his -999 count as "the number of times he's been rejected by women".

Does that mean he has been rejected -999 times, meaning 999 girls have actually *accepted* him?

Or, is his count actually "the number of times he has successfully hit on women" meaning he *has* been rejected 999 times, making it a negative number?

His number goes *down* another 1 (making it -1000) when seemingly Hina falls for him (or at least accepts him)?

In episode 3, he states that he has been rejected by 1000 females he admires, so that must mean his count is actually "how many women he has successfully hit on" then, right? Unless he's being deceiving?

Sorry if this is worded poorly, talking about negative numbers and rejection at the same time is hard.

Comment: It goes to -1000 when she yells that she hates him though so I suspect it goes further into the negative based on the number of females who explicitly reject him.

Comment: they might have verbally rejected him, but as viewers we can clearly see that both Hina and Lynn are falling for him. So, since they are falling in love with him instead of rejecting him, his count lowers. Just speculation tho.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Fandom Wiki about Licht Bach](https://plunderer.fandom.com/wiki/Licht_Bach)

> Licht has two separated counts: the ‘first count’ is on his left hand, which reads "-999". This count is the ‘first count’ since it is the “first one seen”. This count is obtained after the Abandonment War ended. Licht and Nana were roaming Althea for 300 years and to “blend in with the crowd”, they decided to get a second count, one like everyone else had. Nana stated that this Count stands for how many girls have gotten close to him. If he turns them down, his count goes down and visa versa. His count becomes -1000 after Hina calls him a liar and says that she hates him. His current count is -1002.
>
> The ‘second count’ is 5700` and this count is his first and original count. This count is located on his long sword near the handle, and stands for how many heads he had cut off. During battle, his count increases tenfold, reaching the amount of 57000 when activating Schmelman's bloodlust genes. Later on, it was revealed that Licht was not using his original Ballot Replica, as the sword he was using was taken from a Ballot Holder who attacked him 100 years ago. Thus, 5700 is not his real count. In Chapter 50, it was revealed that Licht's original Ballot Replica was stored away behind Ende, as Schmelman was scared of the Ballot returning to Licht and with it, all of the other Barons. His original count on his original Ballot Replica is 300000, and reached 1,500000 when activating Schmelman's bloodlust genes. His original count stands for how many people he has killed in place of his friends and loved ones, as revealed after Hina and the others traveled back to the past. It is noted by Taketora in Chapter 53 that the 1,500000 is only 5 times normal, because if he goes higher than that, Licht would lose control of himself due to the bloodlust genes. Since it is only 5 times and Licht’s full power is 10 times or assumed to be, it is possible that when his count is at full strength, it reaches a total of 3,000000 or greater.

Answer (score 0):

As it is worded currently it is the number of girls who have rejected him. After he leaves, she "rejected" him from her heart and so it went down. More explanation may be given later on

Comment: If it was worded correctly, it would be the number of girls who have accepted him, since it's a negative number. If you have been rejected by -1000 girls, that means he has been accepted by 1000 girls. I think the wording is actually just off. His number actually means the number of girls who have accepted him, meaning 1000 girls have rejected him. Nana's number is how many people love her cooking. Her number goes up if someone loves it, if someone hates it it goes down. If her number was "how many people hate her cooking" it would be -77 because 77 people have told her they love her cooking.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's how many girls have rejected you wich is negative because he has been accepter by 999 (1000) girls. Hina's saying that she hates him came down to me like some kinda love hate thingie, she actually likes him... maybe..?